# Calculating sliding averages

Tags: javascript, python, c, sliding

I'm not even sure what sliding average is, but someone told me it would help with something I'm working on.

I have a table of random values -- `table[n] = random(100) / 100`

I need to populate `table2` with their sliding averages.

I think this is the terminology. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: -1: "someone told me".  And you couldn't ask them?  They know what they're talking about.  We have no idea what they said.

Comment: S. Lott: He said it a while back when I wasn't around on an IRC channel, answering a question of mine about fourier transforms. Why don't you be a little nicer, eh?

Comment: How can we guess?  This isn't a "nice" issue.  It's a "how can we guess what they meant" issue.  How are we supposed to know what conversation you had in an IRC channel?  What kind of ESP are we supposed to use?  How can we know if we're right?  How can we offer answers up?

Comment: It's simple. Do what smmv did. You're question to me was malicious in nature.

Comment: Malice is your perception. You are entitled to it.  Indeed, you can have any emotional response that makes you happy. We still have no idea what conversation happened or how to interpret your question.  The answer you choose to accept must be random, making it hard for us to actually be "helpful".  All we're doing is guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) entry on Wikipedia might be a good start.

Comment: Ah, I saw an question here on Stack Overflow regarding moving averages. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Sliding Average" is another term for "Moving Average" AKA "Boxcar Average".

All are a form of [Smoothing](http://www.wavemetrics.com/products/igorpro/dataanalysis/signalprocessing/smoothing.htm) the data.